# Paypal preapprovals

Tags: php, paypal

How to make the secondary payment method , i.e. credit card payments, mandatory in the preapproval api of paypal in php ? 
I have studied the api docs but have found nothing related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible; Preapproval would require the 'buyer' to have an existing PayPal account, or create one.